# Weird error with Chrome Webdriver | Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to make a simple web scraper with Selenium. Although it's executing the code. I'm still getting this strange error that I can't find the source for:

> DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53078/devtools/browser/bb622515-0b7b-4425-9826-20109518481a
>   [17396:18392:0426/171303.079:ERROR:browser_switcher_service.cc(238)] XXX Init()

Not sure if I should just ignore it? It's just bugging me that I can't find out why!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing logging level ?
chromeoptions.add_argument('--log-level=3')

or disable extensions ?
found issue on https://github.com/giggio/node-chromedriver/issues/140

For hardcore **scraping**, it's easy & fast to use a free **scraper** tool rather than using selenium which is slow.

Comment: Yeah., I was trying to learn Selenium. I couldn't get it to stop that error. But it's not affecting anything. So I guess I'll ignore it now. Thank you